# qt - Pushing multiple QPushButtons at the same time

Tags: c++, qt

I couldn't find an answer to this so here goes nothing:
I'm developing a GUI for an embedded Linux and it needs to be able to push 2 buttons and do different functions when one of the 2 is already pushed (like a shiftbutton on your keyboard). I tried using `button->setAutoRepeat(true);`
It does what it says but it doesn't allow other buttons to be pressed at the same time. The embedded Linux system has a 10-finger touchscreen so it should allow multiple buttons at the same time.

TL;DR: I can't find a way to press another button while a button is already pressed.

Comment: I don't think QWidgets support proper multitouch. So you will have to first of all track mouse events to see what events are generated when you do multitouch in different ways. `QEventFilter` is great class for this, avoiding the need to do subclassing. And once you understand what happens at Qt event level, then you need create custom buttons (subclassing `QPushButton` is probably the way to go) which do what you want.

Comment: Alternatively, consider re-doing the UI with QML / Qt Quick

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1: 
Use QAbstractButton::isDown() to check if the shift like button is down when processing event in the action button.

Solution 2:
QAbstractButton hsd setChecked/isChecked functions which can be useful.

Solution 3: 
Subclass the QPushButton and reimplement keyPressEvent or you can install event filter for your button and process QMouseEvent. This solution will give you more flexibility in your code.

Choose one of it depending on usage and requirement.